# Maven dependency is empty

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Dir Structure:

```
    sample1
       src/main/java   
          com.folder.name.we.like1
             App.java
```

Similarly i have sample2 which contains `com.folder.name.we.like` and `App.java`

I want to add `sample2` as a dependency for `sample1`

modified pom.xml as follows

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.folder.name.we.like</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
```

I have `sample2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` in my repository also. But i check the maven dependencies folder under eclipse. It has `junit jar[another dependency] and wmpty sample2 folder` Why? How do i add my jar here?

Do i need to use `systempath and system scope in my dependency`? Any reasons?

**EDIT**

sample1 co-ordinate:

```
<groupId>com.folder.name.we.like1</groupId>
<artifactId>sample1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

sample2:

```
 <groupId>com.folder.name.we.like</groupId>
 <artifactId>sample2</artifactId>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

[image]

Comment: Both of your projects (sample1 and sample2) should have `pom.xml` describing their attributes (groupId,artifactid and version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually standard Eclipse foo, showing the folder like that. It represents a project you have open elsewhere in Eclipse. It doesn't duplicate the whole tree because you can get to it from the `sample2` project.

If you'd rather see it as a jar like any other, right-click on the project, select `Properties` and then select `Maven` and uncheck the "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects" checkbox.

Comment: Oh, and you can right-click on the "empty folder" and choose "Go to Project" and it will--you know, for those times you have thirty projects open at once and can't find the right one right away.