# Giving preference to one jar over another

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have to refer generic `JSONObject`.

`import statement:`

```
   import org.json.JSONObject;
```

is in my project.

But it is loading `org.json.JSONObject` from cdh hive jar instead our custom one which is generic.

I found it by typing `ctrl+shift+t` It shows hive jar as used and other jars in the workspace.

How do i refer custom one? cdh jar is maven dependency.

**EDIT:**

Both jars are added as maven dependency. So i couldn't find a way to give preference in eclipse.

Moreover [Common project is showing as empty folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715186/maven-dependency-is-empty) and hive jar is there.

It takes `org.json.JSONObject` from hive.

[image]

Comment: Specify your jar first in the class path

Answer (score 3):

You just need to put the jar file you want earlier in the build path in Eclipse, or earlier in the classpath in general. You might want to have a look for a version of CDH / Hive (I haven't used them) which *doesn't* come bundled with a copy of the JSON libraries - just for sanity's sake, only having a single copy of any one class in your classpath is a good idea.

Alternatively, if CDH already comes with the JSON library, do you *need* your own separate copy? Could you delete that and just use the one in CDH?

Comment: Yes we need custom one. Since we have added support for generic JSONObject and few more.

Comment: @GopsAB: If you right-click on the Maven Dependencies, does it allow any sort of prioritization? Perhaps you should build your own version of CDH which doesn't have the JSON support there - or move your fork into a different package.

Comment: I shouldn't move it to diff package. And I couldn't see any prioritization option, I see build path option. In which, I see up bottom options, But It is not showing for separate jars. It's showing for folders.

Comment: @Gops: Well, I've given you all the options I can think of at the moment. I've no idea what you mean by "up bottom options".

Comment: Final Try, You can see the added pictures